# How come my script that allows me to control my elements with arrow keys wont work?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

```
var  div=document.getElementById("myDiv")
div.style.backgroundColor="blue";
div.style.display="block";
document.onkeydown=function(r){
    switch(r.key){
        case "ArrowRight":
        div.style.position="left:"+100+"px"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make it where when you press the right arrow the position of the div goes `left:100px`.

The only error is on line 7 where I said:

```
div.style.position="left:"+100+"px"
```

When I replaced that line with an alert command it worked so I know the problem is with how i tried to change the position. How I can fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `div.style.position="left:"+100+"px"`, try:

```
div.style.position="absolute"; // or one of the other css position properties, depending what you want this to be relative to
div.style.left=100+"px";
```

If you want the div to move by 100 pixels each time, then you could so something like:

```
var  div=document.getElementById("myDiv")
div.style.backgroundColor="blue";
div.style.display="block";
div.style.position="absolute";
var x = 0;
document.onkeydown=function(r){
    switch(r.key){
        case "ArrowRight":
        x+=100;
        div.style.left=x+"px";
    }
}
```

Comment: Full code would be:

    `var  div=document.getElementById("myDiv");
    div.style.backgroundColor="blue";
    div.style.display="block";
    document.onkeydown=function(r){
        switch(r.key){
            case "ArrowRight":
                div.style.position="absolute";
                div.style.left=100+"px";
        }
    }`

If it doesn't work, can you please report any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: The problem is when you press the right arrow the first time,it moves,but when you press it again it stays still.Your code has an error.Try to make it to where for every time you press right the div moves

Comment: Ah, I see now. I've updated the code accordingly. Next time, you might get a faster answer by explaining exactly what you are trying to do in the original question :)